# Как через dropzone по очереди загружать несколько файлов?

Tags: php, ajax

Доброго всем времени суток.
Можете подсказать как сделать загрузку файлов на сервер через dropzone js по очереди через ajax.
Сейчас если добавить сразу допустим 5 файлов то они начинают все сразу же загружаться.
А как сделать так чтобы сначала начал загружаться первый файл, потом если успешная загрузка или неуспешная то второй файл и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать конфигурацию... В документации написано про `parallelUploads` и `autoProcessQueue`.

Прочитайте внимательно документацию, там расписано о вашей проблеме.

Comment: Вообще не то. К чему тут parallelUploads?

Comment: @СергійСергійович у вас же в вопросе про очередь загрузки. Как я понял из документации, эти настройки дают поочередную отправку на бек.

Comment: https://www.dropzonejs.com/ на демо форме при загрузке нескольких файлов они все начинают загружаться, а нужно чтобы если я указал 5 файлов то сначала загрузился 1 файл и так далее.